# Using CC-BY-SA (v3 and v4) content in YouTube video

Tags: creative-commons, cc-by-sa, cc-by

I am creating a YouTube video in which I would like to include some images that have CC-BY-SA (v3 and v4) licenses. I understand that my video would then be considered a derivative work and that I would have to use a compatible license for it.

However, YouTube only allow two different choices: YouTube Standard License and CC-BY. Would it be enough to set the license on YouTube to CC-BY and then write in the description that the license is CC-BY-SA (v4 probably) and link to the license, attribute the original creators etc?

Will this somehow override the less restrictive CC-BY license or will this be an infringement since I have set the video to CC-BY?

Answer (score 3):

If the site where you upload your work to requires you to select a license from a limited list of licenses and the license you want to (or are required to) use isn't in that list, then it is best to select the license that is closest to your desired license but is more restrictive.

Then you can explain in a comment or description what the actual license is. That way you are giving people more rights than they were expecting based on the license indication given by the platform and that is an easier sell than trying to take rights away.

For putting CC BY-SA works on Youtube, this means selecting the Youtube standard license (which is pretty restrictive) and then mentioning the CC BY-SA license in the description.

As the CC BY-SA license is a share-alike license, it is advisable to mention this license also in the credits portion of the video, so the license remains clearly indicated even if the video gets re-distributed.

Answer (score 0):

You should choose the YouTube standard license and then add in the description the license.